# How to manage like button on images in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, facebook-like

I made an icon button for images for giving option to user to like the image but when I go to another page or re-open app the liked photo is again un-liked.How can I make sure that the photo I liked remains liked when if I reopen it?

P.S.-Can I show all photos I liked in a new screen?

```
class FavoriteWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FavoriteWidgetState createState() => _FavoriteWidgetState();
}

class _FavoriteWidgetState extends State<FavoriteWidget> {
  bool liked = false;

  _pressed() {
    setState(() {
      liked = !liked;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        Container(
          child: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(liked ?Icons.favorite: Icons.favorite_border,
              color: liked ? Colors.red :Colors.grey ),
              onPressed: () => _pressed(),
              ),

        ),

      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I except the photo to be liked permanently even after closing the app or going to other screen unless I unlike it..

Answer (score 1):

To let your App remember any kind of data that depends on 2 main factors:

1- The lifetime of your data containers (Variables, DBs,..etc)

2- The scope in which you want to use your data (classes, pages, Apps)

From what i understood in your issue. You want your App to remember the status of a Button after closing/re-opening it.

Normally, most kinds of data variables used in `Dart` being stored in the mobile volatile memory (RAM). That makes them exposed to be cleaned by the OS just after closing your App. That helps the other running Apps to find memory space to work on.

So, storing the states of your Buttons in commonly used variables (Like: `bool`) won't help in your case.

**To solve your problem** You have 2 Non-volatile methods of storing data:

1- Use `SQLite` DB to store your Button state referenced with the button key as a `primary key`. (`SQLite` stores your data in a DB permanent file inside App package). [Read from here](https://medium.com/flutter-community/using-sqlite-in-flutter-187c1a82e8b)

2- The easiest & fastest way: Use a `sharedPreferences` to  store your Buttons states referenced with each Button key as a Key value pair inside the `sharedPreferences [Read from here](https://medium.com/flutter-community/shared-preferences-how-to-save-flutter-application-settings-and-user-preferences-for-later-554d08671ae9)

Hope i could help you